# Pandas' corrwith usage about SPY vs. ^GSPC

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas' corrwith work fine with SPY but not OK with ^GSPC. 
Can anybody help me ? Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas.io.data as web                   
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

Symbol = ['^GSPC','SPY','XLK','XLV','XLY','XLP','XLE','XLF','XLI','XLB','XLU']

STOCK = web.DataReader(name=Symbol,data_source='yahoo',start='2000-1-1',end='2009-3-1')

STOCK['PercentA'] = np.round(np.log(STOCK['Adj Close']/STOCK['Adj Close'].shift(1)),3)

### OK wiht SPY, but not OK wiht ^GSPC
STOCKCORR = np.round(STOCK['PercentA'].corrwith(STOCK['PercentA'].^GSPC),3)     

StockNan = STOCKCORR[~STOCKCORR.isnull()]
StockOrder = StockNan.order().iloc[::-1]
StockRows = StockOrder.iloc[:20]          
print StockRows
```

the error messages:

> > > runfile('D:/@@@pg/yahoo_final_Chang/150830__Revised/test.py', wdir='D:/@@@pg/yahoo_final_Chang/150830__Revised')

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

File "D:/@@@pg/yahoo_final_Chang/150830__Revised/test.py", line 16
    STOCKCORR = np.round(STOCK['PercentA'].corrwith(STOCK['PercentA'].^GSPC),3)
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: When I run with ^GSPC, I got the following error :                                                                                        STOCKCORR = np.round(STOCK['PercentA'].corrwith(STOCK['PercentA'].^GSPC),3)     
                                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: please consider editing your question and add all relevant information. Every error comes with a full error traceback which you may want to include in your question.

Comment: Sorry, the full message is:                                                            >>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\....py", line 682, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Anaconda\.....py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/...test.py", line 22
    STOCKCORR = np.round(STOCK['PercentA'].corrwith(STOCK['PercentA'].^GSPC),3)     
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: There is a `edit` button beyond the tag line in your question. You may want to use it for adding the traceback.